# Docker - Client version is newer than server

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

[Docker daemon in minikube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ioq1w.png)

When I do

```
docker version
```

I have

```
Error response from daemon: client is newer than server (client API version: 1.24, server API version: 1.23)
```

I want to use `export DOCKER_API_VERSION=1.23` to downgrade docker.
But it doesn't work when I use minikube and use `eval $(minikube docker-env)`. The client version is always 1.23

Please see the image about the comparison before and after using minikube docker daemon. The DOCKER_API_VERSION is always 1.23. But the client version is not 1.23.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce the issue with the newest minikube image and the latest docker installation. I think that the cause is that you are using an old version of minikube. Could you check that?

```
 2017-10-04 17:17:34 ⌚  ip-192-168-200-196 in ~
○ → eval $(minikube docker-env)

 2017-10-04 17:17:36 ⌚  ip-192-168-200-196 in ~
○ → docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.09.0-ce
 API version:  1.24 (downgraded from 1.23)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   afdb6d4
 Built:        Tue Sep 26 22:40:09 2017
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.6
 API version:  1.24 (minimum version )
 Go version:   go1.6.4
 Git commit:   78d1802
 Built:        Wed Jan 11 00:23:16 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false

 2017-10-04 17:17:41 ⌚  ip-192-168-200-196 in ~
○ → minikube version
minikube version: v0.22.2
```

Comment: Yeah..My minikube version is 0.20. But I cannot update it because the compatible problem. Is there any other method to just downgrade client docker version?